# How to launch another Win Phone 8 app from URI?

Tags: uri, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I know there is similar question, but it's for Win Phone 7, and the answer is no. Is it possible in Win Phone 8?

Comment: It might be possible, because it is possible to launch any WP app using NFC tag. In theory it could be possible using the Launcher class as well https://ndef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

You can launch some apps by URI as long as the app (internal or 3rd party) has registered the URI "scheme" with the phone.

See [the brief introduction on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_LaunchingbuiltinappsviaURI). You don't have to launch from the `LaunchUri` SDK method, but you can also launch from a web-link in a web-page, for instance.

The listed internal URIs available include launching the browser, email, some settings screens and the Store app.

Comment: This link on Auto-launching apps using URI associations in WP8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx has some examples on registering your own app for a URI scheme and how to handle requests too.